# Is there a surface whose contour projects to the reciprocal of the zeta function?

Tags: calculus, surfaces, curves

> Q: Is there a surface whose contour projects to the reciprocal of the zeta function?

I was looking at this picture and was wondering about the projections of contours of surfaces. Can any analytic function be realized as a projection from a higher dimensional space, like a surface to a lower dimensional space?

[image]

[image]

Below is the reciprocal of the zeta function for reference:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with surface. If $f$ is analytic then $\{( s, f(s)),s\in \Bbb{C}\}$ is an analytic curve in $\Bbb{C}^2$ and its real/imaginary is a surface in $\Bbb{R}^4$. To overcome the problem of the poles of $1/\zeta(s)$ we can consider $F(s)= [1/\zeta(s):1]=[1:\zeta(s)]$ as an analytic map $\Bbb{C\to P^1(C)}$ so $\{( s, F(s)),s\in \Bbb{C}\}$ is an analytic curve in $\Bbb{C\times P^1(C)}$

Comment: Also for most of your questions the answer is : did you see a chapter about it in Titchmarsh, Montgomery, Apostol, Iwaniec and the other books on $\zeta(s)$ ?